# How do you open the chasis of an ASUS VK246 LCD Monitor?

Tags: lcd

Was just hooking my monitor up to my new computer and when I hit the "down arrow" (physical) button (in order to switch the mode to HDMI) it stuck. Now I have a volume control in the middle of the screen that won't go away (because the monitor is constantly getting the down arrow signal). I want to open the case to see if I can get the button to pop up again, but I am at a loss how to open this sucker.

I removed the 2 screws and removed the stand. Then there was one more screw at the bottom with a "warranty void if broken" seal. I don't care, the warranty expired years ago. I removed the one screw under the seal, but nothing is coming free, and there are no additional screws visible. I tried prying the chasis open with a flat screwdriver, and tried to squeeze the back cover in all directions, and even tried pulling on the plastic where the stand fastens (the only place you can grip it), but I can't seem to work out where the clips are that are holding it together to get them to pop open. Although, the edges seem to be more tightly bound than the center.

I did several searches on Google, but there doesn't appear to be any instructions online on how to open this monitor. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the monitor back to ASUS for service. They fixed it within a week and I am back up and running and due to confusion I didn't even have to pay anything (except of course 2 trips to the ASUS service center in another city).

Still, it would be nice if someone posted this type of info online.

Answer (score 1):

I have just opened up a Asus VW246 monitor, which seems the same as the VK246, except it hasn't got a webcam. The problem with my monitor was also that the buttons were stuck.

To disassemble the monitor, follow the following steps:

1. Remove the monitor stand.
2. Unscrew the screw at the bottom.
3. Unclip the front edge of the screen.

### Remove the monitor stand

Unscrew the two Philips screws at both sides of the base. Slide the base down to remove it.

[image: remove base from ASUS monitor]

### Unscrew the screw at the bottom

Behind the stand, in the bottom center, is a single screw, covered with a warranty sticker. Remove the sticker and [unscrew the screw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpTylEbQfKA&t=24).

[image: center screw on Asus VW246]

### Unclip the front edge of the screen

The front bezel is clipped to the back. With the screen side facing you, pull on the edge of the screen to unclip it. Start at the top center, then the sides, and finally the bottom. Pull the plastic edge a little bit to the outside, and pull it loose. Start by pulling with your hands. Using a screwdriver may damage the plastic and the clips.

The picture below shows a clip that has been detached.

[image: Clip]